# Are free online courses worth anything?

Tags: independent-researcher, online-learning, mooc

There’s a lot of non-traditional ways to learn science without actually going to college. MOOC is the first thing that comes to my mind when I hear of free and certified learning. But are MOOCs worth anything? Can you even include free courses in your resume? Will you be able to pursue a graduate-level education by finishing a lot of free online courses that would give you solid foundation on a certain subject?

Comment: Your first question, about listing MOOCs on a CV, has already been asked. (See the duplicate.) I can't tell what your second question means exactly (what do you mean by "be able to pursue a graduate-level education"?) but I suspect it has also been asked already. See e.g. [How do the completion of online courses impact a masters application](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/how-do-the-completion-of-online-courses-impact-a-masters-application)

Comment: Related: [What is the value of a Coursera certificate?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21526/4140)